# Confused by Weighted Fair Queuing example

Tags: algorithm, networking, scheduling

I'm doing an exercise simulating the Weighted Fair Queuing algorithm for network packet scheduling, which can be found under "WFQ" at: http://gaia.cs.umass.edu/kurose_ross/interactive/scheduling.php

*Computer Networking: a Top Down Approach* describes WFQ as a generalized round robin scheduling algorithm:

> WFQ differs from round robin in that each class may receive a differential amount of service in any interval of time. Specifically, each class `i`, is assigned a weight `w_i`. Under WFQ, during any interval of time during which there are class `i` packets to send, class `i` will then be guaranteed to receive a fraction of service equal to `w_i / sum(w_j)`, where the sum in the denominator is taken over all classes that also have packets queued for transmission. In the worst case, even if all classes have queued packets, class `i` will still be guaranteed to receive a fraction `w_i / sum(w_j)` of the bandwidth, where in this worst case the sum in the denominator is over all classes. Thus, for a link with transmission rate `R`, class `i` will always achieve a throughput of at least `R * w_i / sum(w_j)`.

Of the other resources and questions I've read regarding WFQ, none deal with this specific problem since here we assume every packet is the same length and can only be sent out serially every second.

So with this said, I'm struggling to understand how the following answer was derived for the following instance of the problem.

The weights (not shown in the screenshot) are **class 1: 0.5, class 2: 0.3, class 3: 0.2**

[image: Instance of the problem I was given]

In particular, one point of confusion is why we're going from sending two packets from class 1, then to two packets of class 3, then to one packet of class 2 whilst skipping over class 1 (while it has queued packets) on the next cycle.

An answer (and some pseudocode ideally) would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Weighted Fair Queuing isn't applicable at all in practice today, so don't worry about this too much.

Nevertheless, I think this code should help clear up your confusion:

```py
def wfq(packets):
    print('=== Weighted Fair Queuing ===')

    def any_bucketed(buckets):
        return any(len(queued) > 0 for _, queued in buckets.items())

    # sort by time
    packets = deque(sorted(packets, key=lambda p: p[1]))

    t = 0

    bucket_types = sorted(set(c for _, _, c in packets))
    buckets = dict((c, deque()) for c in bucket_types)
    sent = dict((c, 0) for c in bucket_types)
    rr_index = 0

    # packets yet to be received or transmitted
    while packets or any_bucketed(buckets):
        # queue all packets that have arrived by this timestamp
        while packets and t >= packets[0][1]:
            i, _t, c = packets.popleft()
            buckets[c].append(i)

        # if any packets waiting, service one
        if any_bucketed(buckets):
            # cycle until you find a non-empty bucket
            while not buckets[bucket_types[rr_index]]:
                rr_index = (rr_index + 1) % len(bucket_types)

            # calculate weight for this class
            weight_here = weights[bucket_types[rr_index]]
            total_weight = sum(weights[c] for c, queued in buckets.items() if len(queued) > 0)
            weighting = weight_here / total_weight

            # service this class if weight qualifies
            total_sent = sum(sent.values())
            if total_sent == 0 or sent[c] / total_sent < weighting:
                print(f'at t = {t}: {buckets[bucket_types[rr_index]].popleft()}')
            
            rr_index = (rr_index + 1) % len(bucket_types)

        t += 1
```

Try running it with the following data (from your example) and you should get the answer you want in the example. Happy coding!

```
weights = {1: 0.5, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.2}
times = [0.27, 0.76, 1.14, 1.86, 2.24, 2.85, 3.49, 3.74, 4.46, 4.72, 5.51]
classes = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3]
packets = [(i + 1, t, c) for i, (t, c) in enumerate(zip(times, classes))]
answer = [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 3, 4, 10, 7, 8, 11]
```

Comment: Your script fails on the example.... I get: [1, 2, 5, 3, 9, 6, 4, 10, 7, 8, 11]